# Limits of function with 2 variables

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Consider the following functions:

$$f(x,y) = \dfrac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

$$h(x,y) = \dfrac{x^3y^2}{x^6+y^4}$$

I need to determine the limits as $ (x,y) \to (0,0)$.
I know have the defintion:

> For $ a \in U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p: $
>   $$\lim \limits_{x \to a}f(x) = L \Leftarrow\Rightarrow \forall \epsilon>0,  \exists \delta>0, s.t. \forall x\in U, ||x-a||<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon. $$

I also have this following claim, that if I can find $2$ paths that starts at the point $a$ with different limits, then the limit does not exist.

I am quite lost on how to prove with $2$ variables. Can someone point me to the right procedure of even first getting the intuition if such limits exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using polar coordinates
$$\begin{cases}
x = \rho\cos{\varphi}, \\
y = \rho\sin{\varphi},
\end{cases}
$$ we have that
$$f(\rho\cos{\varphi}, \, \rho\sin{\varphi}) = \frac{\rho^3(\cos^3{\varphi} + \sin^3{\varphi})}{\rho^2} = \rho(\cos^3{\varphi} + \sin^3{\varphi}).$$
Therefore, $\vert f(\rho\cos{\varphi}, \, \rho\sin{\varphi}) \vert \leqslant 2\rho \underset{(x,\,y)\to (0, \, 0)}{\to}0.$

Choose an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0.$ Then  there exists $\delta > 0,$ for example, $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon }{4} ,$ such that $\left \Vert (x,\,y) - (0,\,0) \right\Vert < \delta $ and $\left| f(x,\,y) \right| \leqslant 2\delta = 2\cdot \frac{\varepsilon }{4}  < \varepsilon.$

Can you explore the existence of second limit?

Comment: We have yet to learn polar coordinates, if we will at all, but this is clear.
How would I prove this using the definition? We did not practice this at all unfortunately..

Comment: I added some explanations to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Guide：

Here are somethings to try.

- Using polar coordinate might help.
- Try a few paths. In particular, you might like to try $y=x$, $y=x^{1.5}$, also, paths along the axes are common stuff to try.

Answer (score 0):

First fix $y.$ Then allow $x\to 0.$ If the limit exists, you have a function of $y$ alone. Now allow $y\to 0.$

Applying it to the first of your functions gives, as $x\to 0,$ the expression $$y^3/y^2=y.$$ Now allow $y\to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

These limit in two variables are best done by changing to polar coordinates. Let $x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$. Then $f(x,y)=r(\cos^3(\theta)+\sin^3(\theta))$ and you should be able to see easily from this what the limit is (Hint: both $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ are at most 1 in absolute value...).

To do the other problem, after you substitute, you will get 
$$g(x,y)=r\frac{\cos^3(\theta) \sin^2(\theta)}{r^2\cos^4(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)}.$$
This is a bit harder. The $r$ in front of the fraction is going to zero of course. But what  is the denominator going to do? That will depend on $\theta$. First consider the case that $\theta$ remains away from $0$ or $\pi$. Then we can find some positive number $a$ such that $\sin^4(\theta)$ is at least $a$, and so the denominator is at least $a^4$, which means that the fraction is at most $1/a^4$. So the $r$ in front will make sure that $g(x,y)$ will go to zero in this case. But what if $\theta$ is also going to $0$? One way to figure out what happens intuitively is to replace $\sin(\theta)$ with $\theta$ and $\cos(\theta)$ with 1 (the first term in their Mclaurin expansion). You then get 
$$g(x,y)\approx \frac{r\theta^2}{r^2+\theta^4}$$
and taking for example $r=\theta^2$, we see that the fraction doesn't go to zero at all (it actually remains constant...). This gives us an idea of what to do: put $r=\theta^2$ in the expression for $g(x,y)$ and let $\theta$ go to zero. Then we get a non-zero limit. But if we keep $\theta=\pi/2$ (for example) $g(x,y)$ is actually always zero. So the limit cannot exist.